# Change user and load entire environment in shell script

Tags: environment-variables, login, path, su

I'm having some trouble with an upstart script of ours that changes user and starts up a few ruby daemon processes.

In the past i would simply `bash -c "do the business" -l someuser` making sure to use the `-l` flag to emulate a login.

This has worked great until now, our ruby process has been throwing the following error: `require: no such file to load -- rubygems (LoadError)` after some investigation I found this error only occurs when I run the script as the root user, i.e. (when I `sudo su` or when being run by upstart).

I think this is a PATH issue as when I manually set the path first it resolves the issue.

Is there a way to change user and load the **entire** environment?

I have also tried `su user -c` and `sudo`.

---

To make it easier to test I'm "rooting up" (`sudo su`) and running `which bundle` (bundle is a ruby thing).

Here's what I get:

- `sudo -i -u webuser which bundle` # => no output
- `su -l webuser -c which bundle` # => no output
- `sudo su - webuser -c which bundle` # => no output

But ssh'd in as webuser

- `which bundle` # => /opt/ruby/bin/bundle

Comment: Have you tried `su - user -c`?

Comment: What distribution is it?

Comment: Does your script depend on per-user installed ruby modules?

Comment: @artistoex it's ubuntu :)

Comment: @Keith nah... usually I'd install per user with RVM, but this is a client's server and they've manually compiled and installed to /opt/ruby

Comment: I'd make sure it is really a PATH issue (dump the variable in the script).  Then compare the PATHs and look at `/etc/profile` `~/.bash_profile` `~/.bash_login` and `~/.profile`.  For login shells, bash evaluates these in the given order.

Comment: Ah good shoud @artistoex, turns out the problem was they were setting the path in .bashrc which only gets sourced for interactive sessions!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `sudo su - user -c` will make it as though you logged in as that person inheriting their path. That's why `su user` is different from `su - user`.

However if you are setting the path in a `.bashrc` file it will only take effect for interactive sessions (i.e. ssh-ing in as that user).

You should instead use `.bash_profile` or `/etc/profile`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415403/whats-the-difference-between-bashrc-bash-profile-and-environment).

Comment: You should note that `su -` and `su -l` are synonymous.

Comment: and should probably recommend `--login` for readability.

Answer (score 4):

For the login context use either:

- `sudo -i -u USER COMMAND`
- `su -l USER -c COMMAND`